# button to hide background animation

Tags: javascript

I'm searching for a way to get this working:

I want to have a button on a site, which controls the background animation. It should "fade out" (directly, no latency) the whole background animation by click, but by clicking again, it should "fade in".

I tried this:

```js
if (document.querySelector('.Welle').style.display == 'none'){
    document.querySelector('.Welle').style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    document.querySelector('.Welle').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<a type="button" value="Klicken um Hintergrundanimation zu beenden" onclick="backgroundbutton()" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <button>
        Hintergrund
    </button>
</a>
```

but it didn't work, what am I doing wrong? Could someone correct me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: To add this functionality you should give the div a `class`. The `class` in your css will then fade in the item when the `class` is present and fade out the item when the `class` is not present. In your JS, you will add and remove the `class` when the button is clicked.

Comment: It's possible that I missunderstuud you, but I already being working with classes, the. Welle defines a class element.

Comment: You are using the the `.Welle` `class` to select the background in the DOM, but you have no styles defined for that `class`. You should add styles to `.Welle`, then remove/add that `class` to the item you are clicking on with your JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var Welle = document.querySelector('.Welle');

function backgroundbutton() {
  // if the display is "none", we return "block", else we return "none"
  var dp = (Welle.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
  Welle.style.display = dp;
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

.Welle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: yellow url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/pwQMS6f.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Welle"></div>
<button onclick="backgroundbutton()">Hintergrund</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works very well, you solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
function backgroundbutton() {
  if (document.querySelector('.Welle').style.display == 'none'){
    document.querySelector('.Welle').style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector('.Welle').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Hintergrund" onclick="backgroundbutton();" />
<div class="Welle">test</div>
```